# about_Foreach example: cmd subroutine syntax in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, powershell-5.0

In [this about page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core), there is a code block (below) that shows off the `$ForEach` automatic variable, but it also has syntax like a subroutine in batch.  I cannot find documentation on how this piece of code functions or what the language construct is called.  I believe it's a PowerShell v5 addition, but reading the release notes didn't help me either.  What does `:tokenLoop foreach ($token in $tokens)` represent?

```
function Get-FunctionPosition {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType('FunctionPosition')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [System.String[]]
    $Path
  )

  process {
    try {
      $filesToProcess = if ($_ -is [System.IO.FileSystemInfo]) {
        $_
      }
      else {
        Get-Item -Path $Path
      }
      foreach ($item in $filesToProcess) {
        if ($item.PSIsContainer -or $item.Extension -notin @('.ps1', '.psm1')) {
          continue
        }
        $tokens = $errors = $null
        $ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($item.FullName, ([REF]$tokens), ([REF]$errors))
        if ($errors) {
          Write-Warning "File '$($item.FullName)' has $($errors.Count) parser errors."
        }
        :tokenLoop foreach ($token in $tokens) {
          if ($token.Kind -ne 'Function') {
              continue
          }
          $position = $token.Extent.StartLineNumber
          do {
            if (-not $foreach.MoveNext()) {
              break tokenLoop
            }
            $token = $foreach.Current
          } until ($token.Kind -in @('Generic', 'Identifier'))
          $functionPosition = [pscustomobject]@{
            Name       = $token.Text
            LineNumber = $position
            Path       = $item.FullName
          }
          Add-Member -InputObject $functionPosition -TypeName FunctionPosition -PassThru
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      throw
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing two constructs; see [about_break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: So it's a label for a loop for use with the break statement.  Do you know if this has always been a part of PowerShell or added with a specific version @JeffZeitlin ?  I couldn't find "this was added in X" on the about page.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Labels have been in ps since at least v 3.0 (they're described in the v3 language spec)

Comment: The page doesn't exist for 2.0, so I would assume that it was added to 3.0.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin There is no online help for v2. Does that mean PowerShell v2 never existed? As for labels: them work in v2 and, IIRC, also work in v1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell <strike>version 3.0 and up</strike> (at least since version 2.0), the following statement types are *optionally labelled*:

- `switch`
- `foreach`
- `for`
- `while`
- `do`

Now, what does this mean? It means that you can supply a label name as an argument to `break` or `continue` statement inside the body of your labeled statement and have the flow control apply to the statement indicated by the label.

Consider this example:

```
foreach($Name in 'Alice','Bob','Charlie'){
    switch($Name.Length){
        {$_ -lt 4} {
            # We don't have time for short names, go to the next person
            continue
        }
        default {
            Write-Host "$Name! What a beautiful name!"
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Let's process $Name's data!"
}
```

You might expect the "Let's process [...]" string to appear only twice, since we `continue` in the case of `Bob`, but since the immediate parent statement is a `switch`, it didn't actually apply to the `foreach` statement.

Now, if we can explicitly state that we want to continue the `foreach` loop rather than the switch statement, we can avoid that:

```
:outer_loop
foreach($Name in 'Alice','Bob','Charlie'){
    switch($Name.Length){
        {$_ -lt 4} {
            # We don't have time for short names, go to the next person
            continue outer_loop
        }
        default {
            Write-Host "$Name! What a beautiful name!"
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Let's process $Name's data!"
}
```

Now the `continue` statement actually continues the loop rather than the switch.

Quite useful when you have nested loop constructs.

---

Labels are briefly discussed in conjunction with `break` inside a `while` statement in the [`about_Break` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break)

Comment: IIRC, loops labels was in PowerShell since v1. Them certainly work in v2. Although I do not have v1 to confirm it here.